# Hash with a salt in a function

Tags: php, function, hash, salt

i'm sorry for the bad use of English... I'm having a problem with making a function that hashes my password with a salt(first time using a salt).
The problem is that I don't know how to really return the salted/hashed password from the function.

My code:

```
# Password hashing with a salt.
function hashing($stringPassword) 
{
    // Making a random uniq code as salt.
    $salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);

    $HASH512 = hash('SHA512', $stringPassword);
    $hashPassword = $salt.$HASH512;

    return $stringPassword;
}
```

And how I tried to test it:

```
<?php
$stringPassword = '482301';
hashing($stringPassword);
echo $hashPassword;
?>
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What... what are you doing? You're not returning anything useful from your function, and you're calling the function without storing its output into a variable of any sort. Please, start with a basic PHP tutorial.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're having? The second code fragment should display a long string of characters - is that not what you expected?

Comment: @Kryten The second code fragment shouldn't display anything as currently written

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for responding but it isn't helping me... If I echo $hashPassword I'm not getting anything, I know it's wrong but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @ceejayoz ah, you're right. I misread it. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is backwards. The salt has to be part of the password BEFORE you hash it. and then you need to return the hashed password AND the salt, so that you can do proper comparisons later.

```
function hashing($cleartext) {
    $salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    $hash512 = hash('SHA512', $salt . $cleartext);
    return(array('hash' => $hash512, 'salt' => $salt));
}

$foo = hashing('letmein');
echo "Salt is: $foo[salt]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hashing *passwords*, you should be aware that the SHA* algorithms are not appropriate to hash passwords. They are much too fast, instead you need a function with a cost factor like BCrypt or PBKDF2 where you can control the necessary time for the calculation.

PHP offers a dedicated function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate BCrypt hashes, for earlier PHP versions you can use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php):

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```